# Measurability of minimum with respect to lexicographic order

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, order-theory, measurable-functions

Let $f_i:(X,\Sigma)\to\mathbb R^2$ be Borel measurable maps for $1\leq i\leq n$. Consider the map  $f:(X,\Sigma)\to\mathbb R^2$ defined pointwise by

$$f=\min_{1\leq i \leq n} f_i$$

where the minimum is taken with respect to the  lexicographic (dictionary) order on $\mathbb R^2$.

**Question:** How can I show that $f$ is Borel measurable?

**My Attempt:**

A function $g:(X,\Sigma)\to\mathbb R^2$ is Borel measurable if and only if $\pi_1(g),\pi_2(g):(X,\Sigma)\to\mathbb R$ are Borel measurable, where $\pi_1,\pi_2$ denote respectively the first and second projection maps.

By definition of dictionary order we have

$$ \pi_1(f)=\min_{1\leq i \leq n} \pi_1(f_i)$$

so $\pi_1(f)$ is Borel measurable. For each $1\leq i\leq n$ let $A_i:=\{ \pi_1(f_i)=\pi_1(f)\}\in \Sigma$ and define $g_i:(X,\Sigma)\to\overline{\mathbb R}$ by

$$g_i=\pi_2(f_i)1_{A_i}+\infty1_{A^c_i}$$

Then each $g_i$ is $\mathcal B(\overline{\mathbb R})$ measurable and we have

$$ \pi_2(f)=\min_{1\leq i \leq n} g_i$$

so $ \pi_2(f)$ is Borel measurable. We conclude that $f$ is Borel measurable.

Is this correct?

Comment: by *dictionary order* do you mean *Lexicographic_order*? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order?

Comment: @LeonardNeon Exact. I made an attempt in my post.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Isn't there the term $(x, y)\mathbb{1}_{a=x,b> y}$ missing?

Comment: @OliverDiaz The map $((a, b), (x, y))\mapsto a$ is measurable because it is the composition of two projections  $\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^2 \mapsto \mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^2\mapsto \mathbb R$  right?

Comment: @Alphie:Correct. I will write a short answer in a few minutes based on my comments. By all being composition of measurable functions is the key to all.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for any pair $(a,b),(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$

$$\begin{align}
\ell((a, b), (x, y))=\min_{lex}((a,b),(x,y))&=(a,b)\Big(\mathbb{1}(a<x)+\mathbb{1}(a=x, b\leq y)\Big)\,+\\
&\qquad  (x,y)\Big(\mathbb{1}(x<a)+\mathbb{1}(x=a,y<b)\Big)
\end{align}
$$
Clearly $\ell$ is $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)\otimes\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ --$\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ measurable, for $\ell$ is the sum of measurable functions.

If $\mathbf{x}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_n\in\mathbb{R}^2$, then
$$\ell_n(\mathbf{x}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_n):=\min_{lex}(\mathbf{x}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_n)=\ell(\mathbf{a}_1,\ell_{n-1}(\mathbf{x}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_n))$$
It follows by induction that  each $\ell_n$ is $\mathscr{B}^{\otimes n}(\mathbb{R}^2)$-$\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ measurable.

The result in the OP follows as $f=\min_{lex}(f_j:1\leq j\leq n)$ is a composition of measurable functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Looks good now. Do you think my approach is ok also?

Comment: @Alphie: the problem in your proposed solution is the estimation of the projection onto the second coordinates ($\pi_2$). That is why I suggest to start with lex-minimum of two functions where the things become more manageable.

Comment: So you are saying that my claim $\pi_2(f)=\min_{1\leq i \leq n} g_i$ is incorrect? Can you explain why?